# Qiskit finance import error

Tags: qiskit

I am just getting started with using Qiskit and I am trying to run some processes using the `qiskit.finance` package (I am basically following along the portfolio optimization tutorial found [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.24/tutorials/finance/01_portfolio_optimization.html)). However, when I try to import the package, I get the following error message:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseBackend' from 'qiskit.providers'`

It seems that it is likely an issue with Qiskit Aqua since that has since been deprecated and broken up into specific applications, algorithms, etc.

I tried creating a new environment and starting with a fresh install of Qiskit, but that also led to the same error. Is anyone else having this issue? Thanks!

The full error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 6>()
      1 # from qiskit.finance import QiskitFinanceError
      2 # from qiskit.finance.data_providers import *
      3 # import warnings
      4 # warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
----> 6 import qiskit.finance as qf
      7 from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
      8 register_matplotlib_converters()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\finance\__init__.py:45, in <module>
      1 # This code is part of Qiskit.
      2 #
      3 # (C) Copyright IBM 2019, 2021.
   (...)
     10 # copyright notice, and modified files need to carry a notice indicating
     11 # that they have been altered from the originals.
     12 """
     13 ===============================================
     14 Qiskit's finance module (:mod:`qiskit.finance`)
   (...)
     42 
     43 """
---> 45 from qiskit.aqua.deprecation import warn_package
     46 from .exceptions import QiskitFinanceError
     47 from ._logging import (get_qiskit_finance_logging,
     48                        set_qiskit_finance_logging)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\aqua\__init__.py:76, in <module>
     74 from .missing_optional_library_error import MissingOptionalLibraryError
     75 from .aqua_globals import aqua_globals
---> 76 from .quantum_instance import QuantumInstance
     77 from .algorithms import QuantumAlgorithm
     78 from ._logging import (QiskitLogDomains,
     79                        get_logging_level,
     80                        set_logging_level,
   (...)
     83                        get_qiskit_aqua_logging,
     84                        set_qiskit_aqua_logging)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\aqua\quantum_instance.py:21, in <module>
     18 import time
     19 import numpy as np
---> 21 from qiskit.providers import Backend, BaseBackend
     22 from qiskit.transpiler import CouplingMap, PassManager
     23 from qiskit.transpiler.layout import Layout
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not require knowledge about Quantum Computing to be answered. As such, it should be either askep on StackOverflow, or on the dedicated Qiskit Slack channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of the Finance tutorials are here https://qiskit.org/documentation/finance/tutorials/index.html I suggest starting there where you will find an updated version of the one you referenced, which is quite old now from an earlier version of qiskit (0.24). You say you are just getting started, installing the newer versions of Qiskit do not install Aqua, since as you noticed code was refactored into core qiskit and separate application repos.